# Change Login url Laravel 5.2

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

How can I **change default login url** from **http://localhost:8000/login** to **http://localhost:8000/custom**?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change any of the routes that are registered via `Route::auth()` you will need to define them yourself. That method is an opinionated way of getting you started.

```
Route::get('custom', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('custom', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
...
```

You will want to adjust your `auth` middleware, `App\Htp\Middleware\Authenticate` so it knows this new location as well.

From:

```
redirect()->guest('login');
```

To:

```
redirect()->guest('custom');
```